# How to prevent element jump to new row in div?

Tags: css

How to prevent element jump to new row in div? I apply css no-wrap and inline-block to the div but still fail to prevent the elements jump to new row when mobile small screen size not enough width.

See in Demo "lala stich" jump to new row when i limit the div width to 200px :  http://jsfiddle.net/bczap7fy/8/

```
<div class="tree" style="float:left; background-color:#3FC; padding-bottom:20px; white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; width:200px;">
```

Comment: where is the inline block? everything is floating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these styles

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}
.tree {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

.tree {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree" style="float:left; background-color:#3FC; padding-bottom:20px; white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; width:200px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      demo

      <ul>
        <li>
          alibaba
        </li>

        <li>
          michelle

          <ul>
            <li>
              jason


              <ul>
                <li>
                  洪英杰
                </li>

                <li>
                  bilgate
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>
          </ul>

          <li>
            lala stich
          </li>
      </ul>

      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should at least remove all the float property since you introduced flex ... you will create confusion keeping the code like this.

Comment: you are right. i didnt clean up the entire code. not on my pc right now. will update when i get back.

Comment: it works on desktop computer, but not working on viewpot mobile view. I try to remove float:left but still problem exist. Any solution for viewpot on mobile phone browser?

Comment: So you add a draft answer and then you will edit it later ... not a good idea I think ...

Comment: @zac1987 you want the same behaviour on mobile device with less width. and you added width 200px just to emulate small screen?

Comment: if the answer to my last ques is yes, then try adding the overflow:auto to the body tag

Comment: Yes. Adding 200px width is just to demonstrate make "lala stich" jump to new row, because jsfiddle result screen is too small.

Comment: check my last comment about adding body{ overflow:auto; }

Comment: added css body{ overflow:auto; } but "lala stich" still jump to new roll in mobile browser.

Comment: i will look into it when i get back to my pc. :)

Comment: Thank you. really appreciate your helps.

Comment: I checked its working fine for me. Can you show where its not working properly?

Comment: Here. Open with mobile browser, see "lala stich" jump to new row or not http://frx-ct.com/test.php

Comment: its working fine for me :(  even in mobile! its not wrapping to next line.

Comment: finally i found the solution, display:flex is css3 only new version browser support it. My ios safari is old version, so must use display: -webkit-flex;

Comment: ohhh... yeah... Great .. Finally it worked for you :)